# How do I use cold transaction signing?

Tags: security, cold-storage, opsec

Cold transaction signing was recently merged into master.  How would one go about using it?

For those who don't know, this feature allows you to:

1. Create and export an unsigned transaction on an online machine, with a watch-only wallet.
2. Sign and export the transaction on an offline machine with all your secrets.
3. Submit the signed transaction to the intertubes back on the the online machine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to have a cold and hot wallet pair for the same account.

In the hot wallet, make a transaction. It doesn't have the spend key, so instead of actually sending the transaction to the Monero network, it will save the necessary information to a file called `unsigned_monero_tx` (no choice of name for now).

Next step is to transfer that information to the cold wallet's computer. Depending on your degree of security, you may use a USB drive, transcribe it by hand, or find some file transfer program that uses QR codes, or whatever else you want.

On the cold wallet, run `sign_transfer`. This will load that file, and display the details of the transaction, then prompt you whether you want to sign it. If you do, the signed transaction will get written to `signed_monero_tx`. Which you get to copy back to the hot wallet computer.

On the hot wallet, run `submit_transfer`. This will relay the transaction to the Monero network, as well as update balance and spend state of the outputs.

Note that this system does not need the cold wallet to have a blockchain, as the `unsigned_monero_tx` contains all the information the cold wallet needs to sign the transaction. Only the hot wallet needs to talk to the daemon.

Comment: Does this mechanism support transaction ID's? Both after `sign_transfer` and `submit_transfer`, I did not see the transaction ID in the confirmation prompt (v0.10.0.0-38727f7 built from HEAD).

Comment: Retried with a new address, which **seemed** to work.. The transaction ID is visible in the block explorer, but unfortunately, my **change never returned**. I would recommend extreme caution when using this experimental feature, definitely don't do it with large amounts.

Comment: There appears to be a scanning bug for now that explains my previous comment. GitHub [issue 1339](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/1339#issuecomment-260218670) is open for this.

Comment: Other outstanding issues related to offline transaction signing: [1259](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/1259), [1339](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/1339), [1358](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/1358). It looks like these are all fixed, or nearly fixed, in various PRs/branches - but definitely worth waiting for the next proper release before relying on this feature!

Comment: FYI: All 3 issues mentions by @Tom have been resolved.

Comment: Yep, it's all working great now. Also, the Monero GUI app (monero-core) also makes this process even simpler, if you run online (watch-only) and offline (full) wallets (although it does still have some idiosyncracies at this stage)

Answer (score 6):

First, we assume you have a fully-synced node and fully-refreshed watch-only wallet on the hot computer. Also, we assume you have wallet software on the cold computer (don't need the node, just `monero-wallet-cli`).

1. Using watch-only wallet, command `export_outputs <filename>`. There will be a file with `<filename>` created in the working folder*.
2. **Copy** the file to the cold wallet computer.
3. Using cold wallet, command `import_outputs <filename>`*. The cold wallet now has all the outputs and can prepare a signed key image for every one of them (unless something new was received after step 1. It won't display the correct balance because it can't check the spent status of the key images, as it is offline.

--- Stop here if you only want to monitor incoming transfers and don't care to see the correct balance and when something has been spent ---

4. Using cold wallet, command `export_key_images <filename>`. There will be a file with `<filename>` created in the working folder*.
5. **Copy** the file to the hot wallet computer.
6. Using watch only wallet, command `import_key_images <filename>`*. The watch wallet is now aware of spent status for each output and it shows the correct balance (unless something new was received in the meantime, after step 1.

--- Stop here if you only want to monitor the balance with the watch only wallet. Goto 1. after each newly received funds. Continue for cold spending. ---

7. Using watch only wallet and `transfer` command as you would normally, prepare an unsigned transaction. The syntax is the same as if it was a full wallet, but in this case the watch wallet will automatically save the TX to the `unsigned_monero_tx` file* and a message `Unsigned transaction(s) successfully written to file: unsigned_monero_tx` will be displayed.
8. **Copy** the file to the cold wallet computer.
9. Using cold wallet, command `sign_transfer`, to sign and export the transaction. Note that the wallet will look for the file to sign in the working folder*. The signed transaction will be automatically saved to the file* `signed_monero_tx` and a message `Transaction successfully signed to file signed_monero_tx, txid ...` will be displayed.
10. **Copy** the file to the hot wallet computer.
11. Using the watch wallet, command `submit_transfer` and the transaction will be sent to the network. The `signed_monero_tx` file* must be located in the working folder so it can be found by the wallet. A message `Money successfully sent, transaction: ...` will be displayed.
12. Goto 1. because you need the signed key image for the change output.

*Note on folders and file locations, as it could create some confusions. The wallet will look for the files and export them to the folder from where it was started, ie where your command prompt / shell was when you called monero-wallet-cli. It may or may not be the same folder as your actual wallet files or monero-wallet-cli, depending on how you go about it.

For example, your wallet could be on some USB drive like `f:\temp\`, and your wallet software on `c:\monero\` and your shell working folder could be `c:\`.

If you remain in `c:\` with the shell, you could start the wallet by its full path and specify the wallet file location: `c:\monero\monero-wallet-cli.exe --wallet-file f:\temp\mywallet`. In this case, all the import/export stuff would be read/written to `c:\` because that's still your shell's working folder.

It would be probably feel more natural to `cd` into the wallet folder. Do `f:` to change drive and then `cd f:\temp\`. Then, simply start the wallet from that location by its full path again: `c:\monero\monero-wallet-cli.exe --wallet-file mywallet`. Notice how you don't have to write the full wallet path now as you're already there with your shell. In this case, all the files mentioned above would be written or read from the same folder as the wallet files.