# Using the monero cli or gui, how do you sweep all the coins from a private key into your own address?

Tags: cold-storage, sweep-transaction

Lets say I printed out a paper wallet for monero and put it on my website. Now I want to sweep all the coins from this wallet into my own address. How can this be done in the cli and gui? Then I want to delete this private key from my wallet.

Then a few weeks pass, this account has coins again. Do I do the same process again?

Comment: **Note:** A "paper wallet" generally refers to **private keys** (normally in the form of a 25 word seed) stored only on paper (not on a computer).  There is also a stealth address component which you _can make public_ to receive funds, but not spend.  The "paper wallet" should never be "put on a website", only the public stealth address portion (beginning with `4...`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a paper wallet which you received funds to, you don't need to sweep the funds to use them (sweeping means sending all funds to some address), you just need to restore the wallet.

A paper wallet may be a 25-words electrum-style seed (supported by the official wallet), or it can be the two private keys (spend+view).

### Restore wallet using the CLI

Restoring from a 25 words seed:

```
monero-wallet-cli --restore-deterministic-wallet --electrum-seed <your_seed>
```

Restoring from private keys:

```
monero-wallet-cli --generate-from-keys <wallet_name>
```

Then you will be asked to enter your address and both private keys.

### Restore wallet using the GUI

Restoring with the GUI is very straightforward. Open the GUI, choose your language, and then choose the option 'Restore wallet from keys or mnemonic seed' (something like that, depends on your language). Then choose between seed/keys and fill the necessary fields.

### ___

> Then a few weeks pass, this account has coins again. Do I do the same
>   process again?

If you just plan on receiving funds to your wallet, without using them, you shouldn't do anything. Receiving funds does not require any action from your side. You should restore your wallet only when you want to spend your funds.

Comment: There's nothing to stop somebody (duckx's anonymous benefactor…) from sending more coins to the paper wallet's public address at any time in the future, whether duckx is expecting them or not. It looks to me as if duckx really wants to know how to use the paper wallet as a [backup of a] cold wallet; so perhaps [this question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2426/offline-transaction-signing-what-are-the-details/2427#2427) is applicable here.

Comment: how to do this using the gui for private key only? I'm not going to  use the seed.

Comment: @duckx You can simply create a new wallet via "Restore from seed", then input your seed.  It will then show you all transactions into the address on your website.  You can also spend from there.  If you want to only watch incoming payments, but not spend, you can *create a view only wallet* from the "Settings" tab.

Comment: This doesnt answer my question. I don't want to restore the wallet. I want to sweep the funds from the paper wallet into my current monero wallet.

Comment: Then you should restore the paper wallet and then transfer all the balance to whatever wallet you want.