# Forwarding cold signed transactions from a non matching hot wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, cold-storage

This [SE question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/how-do-i-use-cold-transaction-signing) shows how to use cold transaction signing.

The answer suggests the need for cold and hot wallets to be for the same account.

Is it mandatory for `submit_transfer` ? i.e. 
Can monero-wallet-cli `submit_transfer` signed cold transactions made by other wallets ?

Comment: Yes. Any wallet can submit transfer. You can do it even online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the matching hot wallet may do submit_transfer.

Actually, that's not *quite* true. You could submit a transaction from another one, but this will wreck that hot wallet's idea of what's spent and what's not spent (and might error out, but only after the transaction's been relayed).

This would not be hard to change, however, and seems a useful change. Feel free to open a bug asking for this on https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues.