# How do I setup a cold/hot wallet pair (instructions)?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, cold-storage, hot-wallet, opsec

I recently saw the answer for [this question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/how-do-i-use-cold-transaction-signing/%22this%20question%22) which discusses how to sign a transaction from a cold wallet.

How does one setup a cold/hot wallet pair such as this?

The answer mentions that the hot wallet doesn't have a spend key, this seems like the most optimal setup for securing your coins.

**Edit:** While technically I can see how this question is a duplicate of others, I was intending to ask more for a tutorial on how to setup both a hot and cold wallet. Where as other questions aim for a more technical view of the mechanics of the technology.