# Unable to spend from cold storage

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, cold-storage, watch-only-wallet

I am unable to spend from my offline cold storage, I can see the coins as available on the watch-only wallet. Using the transfer command, I am able to generate an unsigned transaction file.

This file is then signed using my offline wallet, followed by moving my signed transaction file to the watch-only online wallet.

When I submit the transfer, I am getting an error, "verification failed", from monerod.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: did you import all the outputs into the cold wallet before generating the TX? did you already spend something from that cold wallet? Are you using the latest 0.10.1 software?

Comment: Yes the cold wallet is fully updated with outputs and nothing has ever been spent from it as of yet.... yes 0.10.1

Comment: @JollyMort I've Solved the issue..... For some reason only worked with mixing 4 thanks for your help :)

Comment: @riifella can your post an answer to your own question detailing how the mixin selection was related to the problem? This might also be a good issue to raise on GitHub

Comment: @SmartKid I have no idea how the mixing could affect the verification.... i generated a TX using mixing 1 mixing 2 and got the same error was just pure luck that i tried mixing 4 when creating the unsigned TX.

It was my first time using XMR was tricky to understand but I think i got my head around it in the end.

Comment: Possibly you just double spent some outputs, and the last tx randomly selected outouts which were yet unspent, so it worked.

Comment: @user36303 Hi, This was a newly generated wallet which has never been spent from so that rules out the double spend.

Comment: Then you'd have to "set_log 1" in the daemon to see what problem it found.

Comment: [How do I use cold transaction signing?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/how-do-i-use-cold-transaction-signing) could be useful.

Comment: Someone should post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it sounds like two transactions were attempted near each other. This should work in normal circumstances, but being on a (now) outdated Monero version could have caused issues.

For anyone who comes here from Google, you may be more interested in [How do I use cold transaction signing?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/how-do-i-use-cold-transaction-signing)

If you're having what seems to be the same issue as OP or the above link doesn't help, consider posting a new question and providing more detail.