# Cold transaction signing with GUI

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, security, cold-storage

Is it possible to safely complete a cold transaction signing process with the official GUI instead of the [CLI process described here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/how-do-i-use-cold-transaction-signing/5655#5655)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

1. Create a view only wallet (settings page)
2. Open view wallet and create a transfer, save with "Save tx" button
3. In original wallet, click "Sign tx" on send page and select the file
4. in view wallet, click "Submit tx" and select the signed tx file

Comment: Is there a plan to add that functionality in the future?