# Spending partial amounts from a Monero paper wallet / priv send key using the Monero cli without another computer?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, cold-storage

How would one go about spending from a Monero paper wallet / priv send key using the Monero Cli? I want to create unique pub/priv addresses for my users and let them deposit their coins to this address. But when they want to send out, I would need to send from their private key which I have control over.

I know about this similar question: [How do I use cold transaction signing?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/how-do-i-use-cold-transaction-signing) -- but it requires you to have 2 computers. I want to be able to do it with ONE computer using the Monero cli.

Comment: Umm, just send as normal? You keep their keys? You want to make a hosted wallet service? Who's doing the sending then? Please clarify a bit, it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: You do not need two computers to do cold signing. You only want to if you want to keep your private spend key offline.

Comment: Yes I want to make a hosted wallet service. I'm building it in PHP and need to figure out how to manage user addresses.