# Did somebody hacked my wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui

I am using a cold wallet for Monero and created a watch key to check my balance from online system. Today I tried to send some monero to exchange and it shows zero monero.

But my watch wallet is still showing balance.

```
[wallet 41nfBN]: status
Refreshed 1452435/1452435, synced, daemon RPC v1.13
[wallet 41nfBN]: balance
Balance: 5.231453820000, unlocked balance: 5.231453820000
```

GUI wallet I downloaded and restored using spend and view key shows a transfer which is not available in watch wallet.

https://xmrchain.net/search?value=5f504ffc4c89f6c2536f8f465a52370963a7224e764f90f3b6ecf5b0c700f7cc

What kind of transfer is that. Why is it not available in watch wallet ? Did somebody stole my moneros ?

Answer (score 2):

Watch wallet can not show outgoing transfers unless some [steps](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/5655/57) are made (import key images from cold wallet).

If you restore with spend and view key, and you see outgoing TX which you did not make, I'm sorry but then someone somehow found your secret spend key or mnemonic and took your funds.

Comment: Do you know how can I figureout the destination wallet address from above mentioned transaction ?

Comment: With Monero, that is not possible. Only the sender knows the destination address.