# Do any Monero wallets have the ability to create a transaction without broadcasting it, and then broadcast it later?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui, privacy, kovri, remote-access

Let's say I'm concerned with privacy, so I prefer to run a whole node, and I do.  One day, I find that I'm required to pull my node offline, perhaps due to maintenance issues.  During that downtime, I find it important that I spend some Monero.  To use my wallet while my daemon is offline, I know I can connect my wallet to a remote node, but I would like to mitigate some of the potential privacy loss in doing so.

Is it possible to use a remote node as my wallet's `daemon-host` in order to create a transaction, but then later broadcast it through a different node?  That is, can the wallet create a transaction without simultaneously broadcasting it?  How?

Perhaps this additional step would only provide for a questionable amount of additional privacy over clearnet, but a broadcast over Kovri (when it's available) would sure be an improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a watch-only wallet to create the TX. When executing `transfer` command, it'll just save the TX to a file. You can then later open a full wallet and sign & send the TX. It's the same process as described [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/5655/57), only simpler, because you're not using a cold set-up. If you have both wallets in the same folder, you can just have them both opened and execute the commands without having to move the files around.

It's really a work-around because there's no option to have the full wallet make a TX to a file.

Comment: There is, via monero-wallet-rpc.