# Can view-only wallet create unsigned tx via RPC call?

Tags: cold-storage, rpc, view-only

Can I use RPC to get back a string representing the unsigned tx file?

I'd like to split an unsigned tx into QR codes, and I'd like my app to run the process instead of parallel user interaction with wallet terminal.

Also, can my cold app counterpart sign the file via RPC?

The documentation on getmonero.org said no outputs for transfer command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been trying to accomplish exactly what you are describing for the past few weeks and I have come to the conclusion that this is not possible via RPC. You can only do this via the CLI. I am in the process of writing a RPC wrapper around the CLI so that I can make programmatic RPC calls that issue the proper CLI commands. A step-by-step guide around the CLI process can be found here: [How do I use cold transaction signing?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/how-do-i-use-cold-transaction-signing/) but you've probably seen this already. I am using this as a guide for the RPC wrapper.

Comment: I have written a CLI wrapper to accomplish above. Will publish soon. If yours is more robust I will take a look and maybe use for my gui.