# does current monero support submitting signed transactions from file?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I generated unsigned_monero_tx on a disconnected computer, and copied it to a connected one.  I placed it in my home directory, and ran `submit_transfer`.  This gave the error:

```
Error: Failed to load transaction from file
```

which is not a helpful error message.

I compiled the software from master (5fbfa8a65663e807c6500ae9485e898df9b7c470) because I read that the offline signing functionality is broken in the current tagged release (!), and because my old monero softwares all stopped working, because apparently they expect to be continually updated (!!).

The content of my `signed_monero_tx` file begins with the text "Monero signed tx set".

How do I broadcast it using the monero software?

Edit: stackexchange has asked me to edit the question to explain how it is not answered by [How do I use cold transaction signing?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2160).

That q+a describes how to do offline signing with things working.  My question is asking about a case of the software not working.  A bug, glitch.  It fails.  That is what my question is about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use cold transaction signing?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/how-do-i-use-cold-transaction-signing)

Comment: "Possible duplicate of How do I use cold transaction signing? – jtgrassie 13 hours ago" --- no, definitely not

Comment: There is a whole section in [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/5655) about folder used to place the signed tx file.

Comment: @jtgrassie: the wallet process's cwd is the home directory. That is where I am running it from.

Answer (score 1):

Those transfer files need to be read and written using the same version of monero (or similar ones anyway).

Monero needs to be updated about twice a year, so you always have software which can work with the regular updates. Failing to do so means you'll drop off the network (but if others also do, you'll end up on a dead fork). The daemon should warn you if this is the case.

If the computer running your cold wallet is using old software, you need to update it first.

Comment: This is an extremely bad situation.

Comment: The versions are the same, on the software  I used to sign the transaction, and the one I am trying to use to submit it.  Whether `signed_monero_tx` file is present or absent, the error message is the same, `Error: Failed to load transaction from file`, so poor error handling. I guess I'm going to have to dig much deeper and write my own client, in order to be able to safely get out of monero.

Comment: Looks to me like you haven't placed the signed tx file in the correct folder. In the duplicate question, one of the answers points out it has to be placed in the working directory, not home.

Comment: @projix - Can you list the specific version of the wallet software?

Comment: @jtgrassie: I am running it from $HOME.  It is the working directory.

Comment: @dEBRUYNE: Monero 'Boron Butterfly' (v0.14.1.0-5fbfa8a6)

Comment: "If the computer running your cold wallet is using old software, you need to update it first." -- by definition, then, it is not a "cold wallet", if it requires this umbilical cord

Comment: Hmm, fair point. That's one drawback of the updates since they introduce new tx formats, etc.

Comment: @projix "by definition, then, it is not a "cold wallet", if it requires this umbilical cord", to update, just download current version on hot computer to USB drive, then copy to cold wallet. I am confused though now, as you say you already updated in the original question.

Comment: @jtgrassie: "I am confused though now, as you say you already updated in the original question" -- My isolated 2017 setup no longer works. I'm trying latest version with a low value wallet / transaction, to try and get *something* working. It remains to be decided how I would then perform my high-value txs, but having the *something* working would present an option, perhaps with extra checks or an attempt at audit (!).  In general, requiring code updates to "cold" wallet breaks the cold wallet model. Learning lesson, my high-value txs, when they come, will be to exit monero.

Comment: @jtgrassie: "to update, just download current version on hot computer to USB drive, then copy to cold wallet" -- I'm not sure if you're being deliberately obtuse. Can you see the obvious attack vector if the "cold" setup is required to continually receive code updates? Can you see how a setup having to receive such code updates, whether by USB stick or otherwise, can not be meaningfully considered "cold", any more than a network-connected setup is "cold"?

Comment: The only software updates you do on your cold setup are managed by yourself. How did you install in the first place? You must have downloaded and transfered offline. If you do not like Monero's scheduled software update cycle and want to use something else, that's fine. But please, I and others are in good faith trying to *help* you. Not to be "obtuse".

Comment: @projix - That commit is already a month old. Could you perhaps try with the `v0.14.1.0` tag (which was set yesterday)?

Comment: @jtgrassie: you may think you are trying to help, but your contribution is negative. All that is happening, is that you are failing to grasp a basic point, about the nature of an "offline" or "cold" setup, and I am wasting effort repeatedly trying to get the point through. Please refrain from further "contribution" on this question, you have nothing to add.

Comment: Well I'm sorry you find me trying to help you "negative". I will refrain from offering you help further here and on any future Monero related questions you may have on SE. Best of luck.

Comment: @tgrassie: it's not that I "find you negative", in tone or something. It's that, the total value of your "contribution" is worth less than zero.  It has much lower value than just, nothing at all.  If I wanted the entertainment of someone pretending that a remote-controlled computer receiving software updates can be considered a "cold wallet", and I have to try and persuade them otherwise, but, somehow, and semi-hilariously, they insist on pretending like it can, I would just head to my local debating society, or argument clinic, or what have you.  I am not on here for that kind of nonsense.

Comment: "a remote-controlled computer receiving software updates" that is not what I was talking about at all though. At no point did I refer to this. Of course that would be about as far from a cold setup as possible. I am sorry you misunderstood what I was saying. And please remain cordial. This is StackExchange, not Reddit. People like myself are here to try and help people, not be insulted.