# Is it possible to list unspent transactions and use them to create a raw transaction?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I've been working with a bitcoin node for a while, so working with a monero node has seen me searching for features I'm used to with the former. It's common when withdrawing to get the "failed to get random outputs" error, due to attempting too large of a transaction. To avoid that, I'd like to build the maximum size transaction myself. But I'm used to listunspent and createrawtransaction commands for bitcoin-cli. Is there an equivalent for monero-wallet-cli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to list unspent transactions...

You want to list unspent *outputs*, not "unspent transactions", for which you can use the appropriately named `unspent_outputs` command.

> ...and use them to create a raw transaction?

You can use `transfer` to create a transaction using specific address indexes (e.g. the indexes that have the outputs you wish to spend), or `sweep_single` to create a tx using a specific output index and key image or `sweep_all` (specifying indexes to send).

If by "raw" you mean "do not immediately send", you can create a transaction using the `monero-wallet-rpc` versions of [transfer](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#transfer), [sweep_single](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#sweep_single) or [sweep_all](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#sweep_all), passing in the flag `do_not_relay: true`, which will return to you a transaction you can send later using [submit_transfer](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#submit_transfer).

If by "raw" you mean "unsigned", see this QA: [How do I use cold transaction signing?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/how-do-i-use-cold-transaction-signing)

Comment: What version of monero-wallet-cli is this command included in? I don't seem to have it, and it's not in every instance of the docs.

Comment: It is in the docs `help unspent_outputs` (just like all the mentioned commands) and has been present for years.